# (Unity) Why my 2d animation doesn't look smooth?

Tags: unity-game-engine

my 2d animation looks stop a little moment when loop finished and start new loop.
I copied my first animation keys and pasted it to my last animation key time.
And i don't know what it is, but it said i'm using Euler Angles.

What can I do?

link below will show my animation video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-bw8kVD2gkcdq7-gBge3duwctDVXFp94/view?usp=sharing

(as you can see, i'm beginner and even not an english user...anyway, I'll wait for ur advices)

Comment: Have you enabled `Loop Pose`? Also have a look at your animation curves (you can change the view at the bottom left below the animated properties) ..maybe you have a certain easing at the ends so animation starts and ends slower. You would need to remove that easing (see [Using Animation Curves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html))

Comment: Loop pose wasn't enabled, so I did it, but it does't solve the problem. and I'm trying to find a way with animation curves

Comment: @derHugo I solved with animation curves. if you write that in answer, I will pick your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Unity interpolates the animation keyframes with a certain easing curve.

For keyframes that mark a continuous movement this is barely notable or they end up being not eased at all since the movement goes straight on.

However, on the start and end you will have a slow smooth start and end of the animation curve.

You can switch to the animation curve view via the button at the left bottom (below the animated properties) see [Using Animation Curves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html).

There you should see this ease-in at the first and ease-out at the last keyframe. So remove that easing and make sure you have a linear interpolation curve.

See e.g. [How to change animation curves to be linear in editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757541/how-to-change-animation-curves-to-be-linear-in-editor) and set `Both Tangents` to `Linear`

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the animation curves;
[Check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html).